# How do I use profiles to update records

Tags: profile

I have 100 surveys filled out by people already on my database. I want to enable a volunteer to be able to enter these by making available to them only the fields they need to do the data entry. I have created a profile which has a listings view and which is searchable; I have limited the profile to the group in which the 100 contacts are found. So I can find the contact and I get the option to view just the fields I am interested in, but there is no edit option and no inline editing available. Is it possible to do what I want? If yes how would I go about it?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the profile created, you are nearly there.  You need the `Update Multiple Contacts` search action. (In 4.6 the action is `Batch update via Profile`). The action has a limit of 100 contacts so you can update all your surveys in one go, but if you have more than 100 you need to do multiple passes.

In more detail:

- Go to Search > Find Contacts
- Select your Group in the 'in' box
- Search
- Scroll to the bottom, change Rows per page to 100, enter
- Click the tickbox next to the Name header to select all the records on that page
- In the Actions box, select 'Update Multiple Contacts'
- On the next screen, select your profile
- Continue
- You should now have your fields editable
- Note that you can copy the value in the first row to all the others by clicking the symbol in the column header

When you're done with that 100, go back to the search, go to the next page and repeat for the next 100 etc

FYI, for these purposes, the profile does not need to be marked as a listings view, or searchable or be limited to your group.  Those options are for other uses of profiles.

Comment: Great.  If you give it the 'green tick' then it helps others know the answer solved the problem.

Comment: hopefully now done!